# VBA Excel - Open a specific folder or subfolder in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to open outlook from a VBA macro in Excel.  I was able to open it but how do make it go to a specific folder? Let's say the "sent Items," "Draft folder," etc.  Also, how about choosing a folder in another mailbox? I have two mailboxes within my Outlook.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
Sub my_prov_openOutlook()

Dim oOutlook As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Shell ("OUTLOOK")
    '''I would like to open a specific folder under the inbox or under a subfolder
Else
    oOutlook.ActiveWindow.Activate
    '''I would like to open a specific folder under the inbox or under a subfolder
End If
```

Comment: Please use the `Try/Catch` Statement instead of `On Error GoTo`

Comment: @Simo this is vba, not vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `GetObject` with Outlook - use `CreateObject`. Outlook is a singleton: if it is already running, you will get a pointer to the existing instance. If it is not running, it will start up.
Also don't use `On Error Resume Next` - you won't know if you get an error and where it occurs.

```
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
oNS.Logon 'does not do anything if Outlook is already running
set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox
if (oOutlook.ActiveExplorer Is Nothing) Then
  oFolder.Display
Else
  set oOutlook.ActiveExplorer = oFolder
End If
```

Comment: I am getting an error running this code.  It could be something in my excel setup or configuration.  I am getting "argument not optional" when the code gets to "set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace.logon".  I ran the code as you have it with GetObject and then changed it to use CreateObject but still got the same error.  I set using the CreateObject as follows: "set oOutlook = CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")" is that correct?